# GIN INDEX on the table, but PostgreSQL EXPLAIN shows me Seq. Scan

Tags: postgresql, indexing, jsonb, sql-execution-plan, explain

I have a table:

```
CREATE TABLE skill (
    user_id integer NOT NULL,
    data jsonb
);
```

And gin index on jsonb column:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_user_id_knowledge ON skill USING gin (data);

INSERT INTO skill(user_id, data)
VALUES (1, '{"technology": "PHP", "knowledge": 77 }'),
       (2, '{"technology": "PHP", "knowledge": 79 }'),
       (3, '{"technology": "PHP", "knowledge": 97 }'),
       (4, '{"technology": "MySQL", "knowledge": 85 }'),
       (5, '{"technology": "MySQL", "knowledge": 89 }');
```

But when I run **EXPLAIN** query:

```
EXPLAIN
SELECT * FROM skill
WHERE data->>'technology' = 'PHP' AND (data->>'knowledge')::NUMERIC > 50;
```

The output is as follows:

```
Seq Scan on skill (cost=0.00..41.75 rows=2 width=36)
Filter: (((data ->> 'technology'::text) = 'PHP'::text) AND (((data ->> 'knowledge'::text))::numeric > '50'::numeric))
```

Why doesn't the query planner use the gin index I created instead of Seq. Scan ?

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/35f2c/5

Comment: what happens if you only select the data'

Comment: rows=2, that's an almost an empty table. An index scan will never be faster than a sequential scan.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TLDR** Gin indexes don't work on this kind of operator.

---

Looking at the [operators for `GIN` indexes](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/gin-builtin-opclasses.html), you can see that the only supported operators for `jsonb` types are: `? ?& ?| @> @? @@`

See the [JSON Function and Operators](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html) docs on what these mean. Based on your query, it can only optimize the text comparison if you rewrite your query as such:

```sql
SELECT * FROM skill
WHERE data @> '{"technology": "PHP"}' AND (data->>'knowledge')::NUMERIC > 50;
```

Which yields the following query plan:

```
Bitmap Heap Scan on skill (cost=16.01..20.03 rows=1 width=32)
Recheck Cond: (data @> '{"technology": "PHP"}'::jsonb)
  Filter: (((data ->> 'knowledge'::text))::numeric > '50'::numeric)
  -> Bitmap Index Scan on idx_user_id_knowledge (cost=0.00..16.01 rows=1 width=0)
     Index Cond: (data @> '{"technology": "PHP"}'::jsonb)
```

[SQLFiddle to play around in](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/501ea/4)

---

After some further fiddling, your could instead use a normal index which targets these json fields directly:

```sql
CREATE INDEX idx_user_id_knowledge ON skill  ((data->>'technology'), ((data->>'knowledge')::NUMERIC));
```

Which can be used for both conditions in your query.

[Updated fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/6fdaf/2)

Comment: If we take a look at query plan cost normal index is better choice right ?

Comment: @dimmed for the use-case you present, yes. You should do further testing if you plan the expand the schema or use different queries. Normal considerations for indexes apply in any case (storage and insert/update performance)